# How was "three fifths" decided on?

Tags: united-states, constitution, us-constitution

I understand the reasons behind the Three-fifths Compromise, but I don't know how that particular fraction was chosen. Why did the US Constitution have a Three-fifths compromise, rather than a One-half Compromise, One-fourth compromise, or any other fraction?

Comment: Why is the answer in [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-fifths_Compromise) insufficient? "After proposed compromises of one-half by Benjamin Harrison of Virginia and three-fourths by several New Englanders failed to gain sufficient support, Congress finally settled on the three-fifths ratio proposed by James Madison.[5]: 53  But this amendment ultimately failed, falling two states short of the unanimous approval required to amend the Articles of Confederation (New Hampshire and New York opposed it).) ""

Comment: It is worth noting that originally the compromise was about financial contributions to the central government and Southern states wanted a low number or 0 while Northern states wanted a high number or 1.  When it became about political power, the states' positions reversed but there was still a need for a compromise.